# iOS Game Center Leaderboard not allowing ties?

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

This weekend I was working on a game I am developing.

On Level 2 a number of players will get the best score (9 moves).  Rather than placing everyone with the same score in 1st position, the first player to get 9 moves is positioned 1st, the second player to get 9 moves is positioned 2nd and so on.  Is it possible to make them all tied in 1st place since they all have the same best score?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find anything in Apple's documentation that specifically defines behavior for tie scores, but I think that's the expected behavior. What you'll have to do is [retrieve the leaderboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW30) and design your own UI for displaying it.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, The **classic First Come First Served** Scenario. As @mmd1080 recommends, an in-game leaderboard would be the solution.

You can also take the long road and request for this feature (tie condition) to be added to the iOS Game Center, since you are the developer of that application.